# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'null' to data type int

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm getting values from database to a aspx page. while getting values of one column, the column is throwing a value like...

```
null,402,2912,2909,2910,2913,2911,2914,2915,2388,2389,2390,
2391,2964,2965,2392,2393,2394,2395,2397
```

Now it throws a exception

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'null' to data
>   type int.

But I want all the other values of the column except the null...

Is there any way to convert this 'null' to '0', but still all the other values should exist.

Comment: You haven't shown any of the code you're using - there are lots of ways you could be approaching this, all with different ways of handling the null value. Please give us more information.

Comment: Where is the code ? i think you should use, `int.TryParse` instead of `Convert.ToInt32` (i guess you are using it)

Comment: Please provide the code how to get this value null,402,2912,2909,2910,2913,2911,2914,2915,2388,2389,2390, 2391,2964,2965,2392,2393,2394,2395,2397

Comment: In SQL script, you can use.. IsNull(column,0)

Answer (score 4):

Make your data type `Nullable<int>` instead of `int` to allow the converted int nullable values, or on the sql select statement you can do that: `ISNULL(yourcolumn, 0)` to convert `null` to 0.

Answer (score 3):

I would just declare my type as `int? variable;` which is a nullable int type.
That would avoid you getting the exception, and you could easily convert your value to 0 if needed

```
if (value == null)
   value = 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you say you want all of the values except the null value in your results, you could filter it in your select statement with a where clause.

```
SELECT * FROM COLUMN WHERE COLUMN_VALUE IS NOT NULL
```

Or, if you're using Linq to EF:

```
from x in yourObjectContext.yourColumns where x != null
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to change from `NULL` to `0` in the database.
Then you should try this-

```
SELECT CASE WHEN columnName IS NULL THEN '0' ELSE columnName END FROM tableName
```